# Applying Angluin's automata learning to build Tree Automata

Tags: automata-theory

I have two different questions: a broad question (**Q1**) and a specific question (**Q2**).

**Q1**: Is there any established or well-accepted mechanism to learn tree automata based on Angluin's style of learning framework?

An existing work I came across is a [Theory Computer Science paper from 2007 by Besombes and Marion](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397507002289). But it is not clear to me why only positive examples and membership queries are allowed but not negative examples, counterexamples, or equivalence queries when Angluin's style is applied in learning tree automata in their framework.

Another part that is not clear about this work by Besombes and Marion (or simply in the context of learning tree automata in Angluin's style) has to do with how tree automata are built. Here's the sequence:

1. The tree automaton is built based on an *observation table*.
2. The way an observation table is constructed is through a *representative sample* of language $L$.
3. And this representative sample is computed based on a *canonical automaton* $A_L$, a restricted form of the minimal automaton of $L$ to states.

Intuitively, the canonical automaton can be understood as an automaton with the fewest number of states. That is, you cannot find any other equivalent automaton that has fewer states than the canonical one. Equivalent automata are the ones that accept the same language.

And here, the way representative sample is constructed does not seem consistent across different examples.

**Q2**: Is there any consistent way to come up with a representative sample for any language?

Comment: It seems that as to why equivalence queries are not necessary but only membership queries are needed, it has to do with Mark Gold's 1967 paper "Language identification in the limit". Please correct me if I am mistaken.